# Best way to track/trace a JSON Object (a time series data) as it flows through a system of microservices on a IOT platform

Tags: spring-boot, redis, microservices, iot

> We are working on an IOT platform, which ingests many device parameter
> values (time series) every second from may devices. Once ingested the
> each JSON (batch of multiple parameter values captured at a particular
> instance) What is the best way to track the JSON as it flows through
> many microservices down stream in an event driven way?
>
> We use spring boot technology predominantly and all the services are
> containerised.
>
> Eg: Option 1 - Is associating UUID to each object and then updating
> the states idempotently in Redis as each microservice processes it
> ideal? Problem is each microservice will be tied to Redis now and we
> have seen performance of Redis going down as number api calls to Redis
> increase as it is single threaded (We can scale this out though).
> Option 2 - Zipkin?
>
> Note: We use Kafka/RabbitMQ to process the messages in a distributed
> way as you mentioned here. My question is about a strategy to track
> each of this message and its status (to enable replay if needed to
> attain only once delivery). Let's say a message1 is being by processed
> by Service A, Service B, Service C. Now we are having issues to track
> if the message failed getting processed at Service B or Service C as
> we get a lot of messages

Answer (score 0):

Better approach will be using Kafka instead of Redis.

> Create a topic for every microservice & keep moving the packet from
> one topic to another after processing.

```
topic(raw-data) - |MS One| - topic(processed-data-1) - |MS Two| - topic(processed-data-2) ... etc
```

Keep appending the results to same object and keep moving it down the line, untill every micro-service has processed it.

Comment: We use Kafka/RabbitMQ to process the messages in a distributed way as you mentioned here. My question is about a strategy to track each of this message and its status (to enable replay if needed to attain only once delivery). Let's say a message1 is being by processed by Service A, Service B, Service C. Now we are having issues to track if the message failed getting processed at Service B or Service C as we get a lot of messages.

Comment: Each micro service is following an event driven approach, that is, it consumes messages from Kafka/RabbitMQ and posts them back to RabbitMQ/Kafka for next consumer service to process them down streams. Also each service has it is own db. The question is regarding the best way to track each message..

Comment: keep a failure topic attached to every micro-service, so that if anything goes wrong push that packet to corresponding failure queue, instead pushing it to input topic of next microservice.

Comment: keep appending the microservice results to main object instead of modifying its properties, to track previous computation results. However, object size will increase depending upon fields you have to process but, that's manageable i think.